# Why does this codeblock execute after Rails.cache.fetch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, codeblocks

I have this line of code which performs exactly what I want it to do. But I have no idea why it works.

```
  Rails.cache.fetch(key, expires_in: 1.day) do
    a << b
  end
```

What it is supposed to do is add b to a if the key does not exist in the Rails cache.

Why i'm confused?

```
      Rails.cache.fetch(key, expires_in: 1.day)
```

returns nil, regardless if the key was already in the cache.

question:
why does the code block run when there is no key in the cache, but doesn't run otherwise?

Extra details: Rails cache is connected to Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be confusing that the `do ... end` block is evaluated although `Rails.cache.fetch` returns `nil`. But the `do ... end` block doesn't run on top of the `nil` response.

In fact, the `do ... end` block is an additional argument to the `fetch` method call. Have a look at the [source code of `fetch`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L306).

Without a block `fetch` basically does only one thing – calling `read(name, options)` in line 328. But with a block it way more (lines 307 to 324)

Comment: fabulous thanks. This also led me to a solution to my spec problems. 'allow(Rails.cache).to receive(:fetch).and_yield' solved them